# DVD Drive not visible in Wine

Tags: 11.10, wine

Before anything else, Ubuntu mounts DVD's with no problem.

The problem is with Wine. I can't configure it so the DVD drives appear on the list.

I have tried a couple of solutions that I found on the forums, that define the route

Comment: and by list you mean?

Comment: The list of devices. That is, Wine config, and "Drives" tab.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file with the the .desktop extension and make it contain something along the lines.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=mspaint
GenericName=Microsoft Paint
Comment=Microsoft Paint
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=
Exec=/media/Windows/WINDOWS/system32/mspaint.exe
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/apple-green.png
Path=
```